# How to query wss_logging DB

Tags: sharepoint-server, statistics, log

I've a site with a lot of sub site and i'd like to do some query in the table RequestUsage to retrieve the pages consulted by user, site

The pages edited by user , site, Pages deleted etc.

I don't know which table, which filter use?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057/en-us

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your link

Comment: It's unsupported to query SharePoint databases, just a heads up.

Comment: it's false, the db wss_logging is there for reporting

Comment: It's true, and yes the wss_logging is there for reporting but to directly query the db is not supported. Use the object model or enable auditing settings on a site to get ootb webparts for reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it’s fully supported by Microsoft to directly read, query and build reports from the logging database. As per TechNet:

> A single place that stores various monitoring information helps you
>   efficiently monitor SharePoint Server 2010 servers and services. More
>   importantly, you can create your own reports for unique monitoring,
>   reporting and troubleshooting requirement based on tables inside the
>   logging database. This article describes how to create reports using
>   existing tables and views.

MSFT provide you some pre-define views and you can also write your own views as well.

[Pre-defined SQL views in the logging database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769360(v=office.14).aspx#section2)
[Custom SQL views in the logging database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769360(v=office.14).aspx#section3)

Also check this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70865/SharePoint-Logging-Database